# NestJS + Firebase realtime database / configuration

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, nestjs

I want to connect Firebase Realtime Database to my Nest.js application. I have a question regarding the configuration, as I'm not quite sure what to use. In general, my application is very simple; I have a database of 7 thousand objects that will be fetched from the frontend through the backend, optionally filtered (read-only). I understand that I use only server-side authentication, which receives data and sends it to the frontend. What is the difference between 'web' and 'admin,' and is 'web' with 'only-read' sufficient for my application? Which configuration set should I use? So far, I have been using TypeORM for Nest, but with Firebase, it works a bit differently, and I don't fully understand from the documentation what and where I should apply to connect and retrieve data. I would be grateful for your help. Love you.

Connect to realtime database from my Nestjs application